# Estimate $\sum\limits_kk(1-p^{k})^N-k(1-p^{k-1})^N$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an explicit formula for the sum of the series
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}k(1-p^{k})^N-k(1-p^{k-1})^N$$ where $p\in(0,1)$ and $N$ is an integer?

Comment: Its a divergent series, so the explicit formula for any value of $p$ and $N$ is  $\infty$.

Comment: what is the link with expectation/probability?

Comment: @samo It actually don't, check again, its an infinite sum.

Comment: my bad, it does actually converge, sorry (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Ah, the sweet click of revenge downvotes in the night...*

The $n$th partial sum is $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk(1-p^{k})^N-k(1-p^{k-1})^N=\sum_{k=1}^nk(1-p^{k})^N-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1)(1-p^k)^N$$ that is, $$S_n=n(1-p^n)^N-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p^k)^N=(1-p^n)^N+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p^n)^N-(1-p^k)^N$$ When $n\to\infty$, for every $p$ in $[0,1)$, $(1-p^n)^N\to1$ hence $$\lim S_n=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty1-(1-p^k)^N$$ Now, $$(1-x)^N=\sum_{i=0}^N(-1)^{i}{N\choose i}x^i$$ hence $$\lim S_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i+1}{N\choose i}\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^{ki}=1+\sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i+1}{N\choose i}\frac{p^i}{1-p^i}$$ Note that our last formulas for $\lim S_n$ are sums of a finite number of terms.